# Calculate the hash of Blob using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two `Blob`s to see if there are changes between them.

One way of doing this is by calculating the hash of the blobs and then comparing them, e.g.:

```
hash(firstBlob) === hash(secondBlob)
```

How can I calculate the hash of a Blob and check against another hash to see if they have changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is kind of old but for someone looking for a better and newer solution please use the [Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) and a SHA-256 or higher variant for the algorithm since MD5 has [exploitable](https://www.zdnet.com/article/a-quarter-of-major-cmss-use-outdated-md5-as-the-default-password-hashing-scheme/) flaws.

```
var a = new FileReader();
a.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
a.onloadend = function () {
  let hashPromise = crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", a.result);// it outputs a promise
};
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to get the contents of the blob for comparison. If you have to use CryptoJS for this, you can use `readAsBinaryString`:

```
var a = new FileReader();
a.readAsBinaryString(blob);
a.onloadend = function () {
  console.log(CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(a.result)));
};
```

---

Note that `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated, so if you can use another library, such as [SparkMD5](https://github.com/satazor/js-spark-md5), you could use an array buffer instead:

```
var a = new FileReader();
a.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
a.onloadend = function () {
  console.log(SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer.hash(a.result));
};
```

Comment: @RaymondWu: seems you're correct, fixed the answer. Thanks!

Comment: you sould define the onloadend method before the call to readAsBinaryString or readAsArrayBuffer : otherwise, with a small enough buffer, you might get the onloadend event handler registered after the event was triggered

Comment: @Thierry: I don't think that's ever happened in my experience -- IIRC `readAs*` is defined to be asynchronous, which means the `onloadend` function will be defined before the event is called.

Comment: Asynchronous doesn't mean that. Asynchronous means it might run after the next instruction. It might also run before. In this particular case, we observe that most of the time it running after the next instruction. It is not guaranteed though.

Comment: @Thierry if that was the case, then this would be the case no matter what: http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony

Comment: Well, it is extremely interesting reading, but the guys are discussing how an API should be implemented either async or sync but not both depending on the case. It does not say that every API either async or sync. Then if you look at the javascript spec of `readAsArrayBuffer` : https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readAsArrayBuffer it does not mention anywhere that the API must be async. So the behavior will be browser depend. Setting `onloadend` before calling  `readAsArrayBuffer` will not trigger any issue and is valid, and will not be subject to 'strange' issues (reproductible in debug in firefx)

Comment: Since the behavior is browser specific, and *may* be async, it's best to assume it is. Therefore, it's best to set the event handlers before calling the function that will lead to the event being emitted.